# Seeking advice on accomplishing SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql

So I have 2 SQL tables

Players:

```
P_Id 
Name
```

Matches:

```
M_Id
Player1
Player2
Winner
```

Should be self explanatory, if we had a match id 5 involving player 1 and player 2, with 2 being the winner, the row would be

```
(5, 1, 2, 2)
```

How would I go about getting a list of all players in the form `(p_id, total_wins)` in descending order of matches won?

I've figured out how to get the total wins for a single player with

```
"SELECT count(m_id) FROM Matches where winner = <p_id>;"
```

EDIT:

```
tournament=> select winner, count(winner) from matches group by winner;
 winner | count
--------+-------
      1 |     1
      5 |     1
      3 |     1
      7 |     1
(4 rows)

tournament=> select * from players;
 p_id |       name
------+-------------------
    1 | Twilight Sparkle
    2 | Fluttershy
    3 | Applejack
    4 | Pinkie Pie
    5 | "Rarity
    6 | Rainbow Dash
    7 | Princess Celestia
    8 | Princess Luna
```

Can i possibly join these two on where  winner == p_id? Also could you explain what kind of join I'd need?

Comment: I take that `Player1` and `Player2` are foreign keys. Is `Winner` also a foreign key or is that just `1` or `2`?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Players.*, NumberOfMatchesWon
FROM Players
JOIN (
    SELECT Winner AS P_Id, COUNT(*) AS NumberOfMatchesWon
    FROM Matches
    GROUP BY Winner
) AS NumberOfMatchesWonByPlayer USING (P_Id)
ORDER BY NumberOfMatchesWon DESC
```

Names are a bit verbose but chosen this way so it hopefully becomes clear how it works. If you also want to see Players that haven't won any match yet change `JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN`.

Edit: This SQL assumes that Winner is a reference to the Players table and not always 1 or 2.

Comment: oh sorry for this late thing. I do believe your thing has done what I asked! Just ran it and am now gonna spend a while dissecting your answer. EDIT: okay could u possibly modify this to work with an empty Matches table?

Comment: When using LEFT JOIN this should work with an empty Matches table. In that case the subselect will not yield any rows but when joined using LEFT JOIN every Players row will be kept, even when not being matched. NumberOfMatchesWon will be NULL then but it can easily be changed to zero using COALESCE(NumberOfMatchesWon, 0). Does that help or are there any issues left?

Answer (score 0):

(**Added note:** I just realized this was about PostgreSQL. For some reason I thought this was MySQL. I have no experience with PostgreSQL, however this is standard SQL which works in MySQL, Microsoft SQL Server and Oracle, so I hope it works in PostgreSQL too.)

---

If `Winner` is a foreign key then it's straightforward:

```
select winner, count(*) from Matches group by winner order by 2 desc
```

If `Winner` is always `1` or `2` (meaning that `Player1` or `Player2` won respecitvely) then it gets a bit more verbose:

```
select
    case when winner=1 then Player1 else Player2 end,
    count(*)
from Matches
group by case when winner=1 then Player1 else Player2 end
order by 2 desc
```

For the query to be more useful you'll probably want to include the name too. It'll be a lot easier (and faster) than to perform a second query and then try to match it yourself. Here are the modifications to do that:

If `Winner` is a foreign key, it's stupid easy:

```
select
    a.winner, b.name, count(*)
from
    Matches a
    join Players b on (a.winner=b.p_id)
group by
    a.winner, b.name
order by 2 desc
```

If `Winner` is `1` or `2`, then... I'll go for a subquery, just to show another method (you could also do it the same way as above):

```
select
    a.id,
    b.name,
    a.count
from
   (select
        case when winner=1 then Player1 else Player2 end id,
        count(*) count,
    from Matches
    group by case when winner=1 then Player1 else Player2 end
   ) a,
   join Players b on (a.id=b.p_id)
order by a.count desc
```

Comment: Ooh as a new learner this is cool. I actually originally planned to use a foreign key but figured I could get away with not using it up until this part of the project I'm doing.

Comment: @JosephPerez - Aren't `Player` and `Player2` fields already foreign keys? That is, they're ID values that match with those in the `Players` table, right? In that case they are de-facto foreign keys. That's what a foreign key **is** - a field with ID values from another table. Explicitly marking them as foreign keys will simply give you the additional benefit of safety - you won't be able to insert/update/delete rows in such a fashion that creates an inconsistency (like a `Matches.Player1` value that isn't present in `Players.p_id`).

Comment: ooh didn't realize that, thought you had to explicitly declare their relationship. okays.

Comment: Hey can I ask help with something else? I was fumbling around on my own. trying to come up with something before resorting to your solution and I ended up with the following

Comment: @JosephPerez - I think you forgot something. :) Also, about terminology - I don't know if "foreign key" officially refers to the explicitly declared thing or simply the construct itself (matching IDs in two tables). You can certainly `JOIN` on anything, even if there are no explicitly defined relationships. But, as I said, explicitly declaring your relationships comes with a number of side benefits, so it's recommended to do it always anyway. :)